# Texture greyed out in render

Tags: rendering, texturing

I was trying some textures out based on Blenderguru's tutorial and this is what I came up with. Does anybody know why parts of the wood look grey and how to change that?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greyed parts of texture are the parts with high reflection, so they reflect black background and this cause this effect.

Glossy shader is connected to bottom input, so value 1 in Fac slot make material pure glossy, value 0 is pure diffuse. This values are stored in texture as a colors: 1 = white, 0 = black.

What do you need to do is change white to grey, so from value 1 to smaller one.

One way how to do it is plug *ColorRamp* node between texture and *Fac* slot on  *Mix Shader Node*. 
Now you can control values by colors. In this case you need to change white to appropriate gray = change value from 1 to less than one.

Also you can moving slides closer together and adjust contrast.

As second - for nice reflections you need something to reflect. Usually hdri environment map. You have black environment in your scene = black color in reflected from your materials = ugly grayed reflections.

Comment: That was quick, thanks! it seems like it worked :)

Comment: If this answer work for you, please consider mark this question as solved. Thank you